# JS not executed on Pebble Time with "notifyWithAppMessage: no delegate" in the app logs

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I have a perfectly working (Pebble Classic) app on the Pebble app store. However, when installed on Pebble Time, the JS is not always executed (or takes too long to kick in) and in the logs I can see "[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: notifyWithAppMessage: no delegate."

Is it Aplite compatibility issue or do I need to do something differently for Basalt platform. App is SDK2, thus compiled only for Aplite.

Note that the JS was not bundled in iOS app yet, so if you want to try it you must use Android app.
https://apps.getpebble.com/applications/5541de234b4d965adb000050

Comment: If your app is compiled for SDK2 this is almost certainly a compatibility problem in the Basalt firmware. Are you running on a physical Pebble Time, or on the emulator?

Comment: I'm running it on developer version of Pebble Time. On Aplite emulator all works just fine. Strange thing is that other watch apps like The Weather Channel work just fine.

Comment: How about on the Basalt emulator?

Comment: I'm compiling it as SDK2 app (on CloudPebble) and therefore can be run only on Aplite emulator. I might change it to SDK3 app and see how it goes on Basalt emulator. Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: @Marcel I just tried your app (from the appstore) with the latest version of the firmware and Android app on Pebble Time and it works fine.

Comment: @sarfata Thanks for this information. It seems that there's problem with Pebble Time beta iOS app. For a reason it doesn't execute the JS correctly or at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Please file a bug via the mobile app.

Comment: I apologize, I'm totally wrong. This should work flawlessly. Can you file a bug through the mobile app?

Comment: I just replied to support email. It is still not resolved. It seems there is some problem with how fast the delegate is requested and how fast the JS in initialised. See log messages:
---
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: JS: stopping app: 9B2C7E21-63EF-4D77-90D6-DAED73054299 Weather.com

[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: notifyWithAppMessage: no delegate.

[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: JS: starting app: 298595A9-00C0-494A-BBCC-BFB9423D6430 Frontpage

[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: JS: Frontpage (Textura): PebbleKit JS started!
---